# Identifying the start and end of a sequence in R

Tags: r, for-loop, case, sequence

The following is a sample dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(
sess_id = c(189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 124, 124,124,124,124),
Activity = c("home", "pg1", "pg2", "cart", "pg3", "pg2", "home", "pg3", "cart","pg1","home","pg2", "pg3", "cart", "pg2"),
ts = c("2002-06-09 12:45:40","2002-06-09 12:46:01","2002-06-09 12:46:30","2002-06-09 12:47:00","2002-06-09 12:47:50", "2002-06-09 12:49:51", "2002-06-09 12:49:59", "2002-06-09 13:00:00", "2002-06-09 13:30:00", "2002-06-09 13:31:02", "2002-06-09 13:31:45", "2002-06-09 13:32:28", "2002-06-09 13:32:30", "2002-06-09 13:32:32", "2002-06-09 13:33:28")),
.Names = c("sess_id", "Activity", "ts"),
row.names = c(NA, -15L),
class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to analyze the sequence in blocks. I want to extract a block of user behavior where the start point is 'home' and the end point is 'cart'. For instance, for sess_id 189, I would have two blocks: home, pg1, pg2, cart and home, pg3, cart.

My idea is to create a new column called index where a 1 denotes part of a block. If 0, I can filter out those rows as not being part of the home to cart sequence.

With the following code I am able to mark the start and end points, but not the Activity between home and cart.

```
df %>%
  group_by(sess_id) %>%
  arrange(ts) %>% 
  mutate(index = case_when(Activity == "home" | Activity == "cart" ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  mutate(index = as.numeric(index)) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(block_index = cumsum(index))
```

I am expecting an output something like this:

| sess_id | Activity | ts | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 189 | home | 2002-06-09 12:45:40 | 1 |
| 189 | pg1 | 2002-06-09 12:46:01 | 1 |
| 189 | pg2 | 2002-06-09 12:46:30 | 1 |
| 189 | cart | 2002-06-09 12:47:00 | 1 |
| 189 | pg3 | 2002-06-09 12:47:50 | 0 |
| 189 | pg2 | 2002-06-09 12:49:51 | 0 |
| 189 | home | 2002-06-09 12:49:59 | 1 |
| 189 | pg3 | 2002-06-09 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 189 | cart | 2002-06-09 13:30:00 | 1 |
| 189 | pg1 | 2002-06-09 13:31:02 | 0 |
| 124 | home | 2002-06-09 13:31:45 | 1 |
| 124 | pg2 | 2002-06-09 13:32:28 | 1 |
| 124 | pg3 | 2002-06-09 13:32:30 | 1 |
| 124 | cart | 2002-06-09 13:32:32 | 1 |
| 124 | pg2 | 2002-06-09 13:33:28 | 0 |

I am open to suggestions and alternatives too.

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R approach is to create a `Vectorize`'d function of `seq` and using `grep` to identify the "from" rows (that contain "home") and "to" rows (that contain "cart"), then subsetting:

```
seqV <- Vectorize(seq.default, 
                  vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

keeps <- unlist(seqV(grep("home", df$Activity), 
                     grep("cart", df$Activity)))

blocks <- df[keeps, ]
```

This will create a new data frame `blocks` that will only contain the desired observations. However, if you wanted to make an index variable and keep the full dataset, you can add that directly in `df` by:

```
df[keeps, "index"] <- 1
df[setdiff(1:nrow(df),keeps), "index"] <- 0

#    sess_id Activity                  ts index
# 1      189     home 2002-06-09 12:45:40     1
# 2      189      pg1 2002-06-09 12:46:01     1
# 3      189      pg2 2002-06-09 12:46:30     1
# 4      189     cart 2002-06-09 12:47:00     1
# 5      189      pg3 2002-06-09 12:47:50     0
# 6      189      pg2 2002-06-09 12:49:51     0
# 7      189     home 2002-06-09 12:49:59     1
# 8      189      pg3 2002-06-09 13:00:00     1
# 9      189     cart 2002-06-09 13:30:00     1
# 10     189      pg1 2002-06-09 13:31:02     0
# 11     124     home 2002-06-09 13:31:45     1
# 12     124      pg2 2002-06-09 13:32:28     1
# 13     124      pg3 2002-06-09 13:32:30     1
# 14     124     cart 2002-06-09 13:32:32     1
# 15     124      pg2 2002-06-09 13:33:28     0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But, this is not working on the whole dataset. This is the error:

Error:
! Row indexes 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, and 176205 more are used more than once for assignment.
Backtrace:
 1. base::`[<-`(`*tmp*`, keeps, "index", value = `<dbl>`)
 2. tibble:::`[<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, keeps, "index", value = `<dbl>`)
 3. tibble:::tbl_subassign(x, i, j, value, i_arg, j_arg, substitute(value))
 4. tibble:::vectbl_as_new_row_index(i, x, i_arg)

Comment: At what step did this error occur? This worked on your `dput` data. Please post your `dput` such that this error could be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `sequence`:

```r
w = which(df$Activity %in% c("home", "cart"))
idx = sequence(w[c(F, T)] - w[c(T, F)] + 1, w[c(T, F)])
df$index <- +(seq_len(nrow(df)) %in% idx)
```

output

```r
   sess_id Activity                  ts index
1      189     home 2002-06-09 12:45:40     1
2      189      pg1 2002-06-09 12:46:01     1
3      189      pg2 2002-06-09 12:46:30     1
4      189     cart 2002-06-09 12:47:00     1
5      189      pg3 2002-06-09 12:47:50     0
6      189      pg2 2002-06-09 12:49:51     0
7      189     home 2002-06-09 12:49:59     1
8      189      pg3 2002-06-09 13:00:00     1
9      189     cart 2002-06-09 13:30:00     1
10     189      pg1 2002-06-09 13:31:02     0
11     124     home 2002-06-09 13:31:45     1
12     124      pg2 2002-06-09 13:32:28     1
13     124      pg3 2002-06-09 13:32:30     1
14     124     cart 2002-06-09 13:32:32     1
15     124      pg2 2002-06-09 13:33:28     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr::accumulate`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
    group_by(sess_id) |>
    mutate(block = accumulate(Activity,
                              ~if(.y == "home")
                                   1
                               else if (.y == "cart")
                                   -1
                               else if (.x < 0)
                                   0
                               else .x,
                              .init = 0) |>
               tail(-1) |>
               abs())

##>    sess_id Activity ts                  block
##>      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>               <dbl>
##>  1     189 home     2002-06-09 12:45:40     1
##>  2     189 pg1      2002-06-09 12:46:01     1
##>  3     189 pg2      2002-06-09 12:46:30     1
##>  4     189 cart     2002-06-09 12:47:00     1
##>  5     189 pg3      2002-06-09 12:47:50     0
##>  6     189 pg2      2002-06-09 12:49:51     0
##>  7     189 home     2002-06-09 12:49:59     1
##>  8     189 pg3      2002-06-09 13:00:00     1
##>  9     189 cart     2002-06-09 13:30:00     1
##> 10     189 pg1      2002-06-09 13:31:02     0
##> 11     124 home     2002-06-09 13:31:45     1
##> 12     124 pg2      2002-06-09 13:32:28     1
##> 13     124 pg3      2002-06-09 13:32:30     1
##> 14     124 cart     2002-06-09 13:32:32     1
##> 15     124 pg2      2002-06-09 13:33:28     0
```